# Need to add custom text field to Woocommerce under add to cart button

Tags: customization, woocommerce-offtopic, widget-text

I'm a WP newbie so please stick with me here.

I handle this online catalog of products and we need a custom input field to go beneath our invisible "Add To Cart" button. The text needs to be changed per product. On the Single Product Page Customizer there is the option to add text after the cart button, but it's a static line of text and not editable per product.

Any help would be amazing.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The easier solution (for me) is to work with ACF plugin, add a custom field to product and display it on the single page with this hook "woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_form".